# Cursor positioning after pasting content in Vim

Tags: vim, paste

When I use the command

```
:r (path to file)
```

it will paste the content of the file that I want. Is there any way to move the cursor to the end after pasting, since command mentioned keep the cursor at where it pasted the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>'</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> moves the cursor to the last yanked/inserted/pasted line. <kbd>j</kbd> moves the cursor to the next line. So `:r filename` <kbd>CR</kbd><kbd>'</kbd><kbd>]</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> should do what you want (line after the inserted text).

Alternately, staying entirely in command-line mode, `:r filename | ']+1`.

(`:help :read`, `:help ']`, `:help :[range]`)

Answer (score 2):

Technically, this is *inserting", not "pasting", and the cursor is not "where it pasted the content":

> After the ":read" command, the cursor is left on the first non-blank in the first new line.

You can do `']` to jump to the end of the last changed text. See `:help ']`.