# Vi(m): How to read file into exact possition in buffer

Tags: vim, vi, editing

I need to read content of another file into **exact position** I am at in the editing buffer in Vi(m). The `:r/path/to/file` (or the `:r!some -command`) inserts new line before the content. As an example consider editing a YAML file like this:

```
---
some:
  structured:
    content:
      metadata:
        uuid: <Esc>:r/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid<Enter>i
_b5806d69-1612-44aa-a30c-9b4312a99b5c
```

What I need is to achieve is to make Vi(m) basically like this instead:

```
some:
  structured:
    content:
      metadata:
        uuid: <Esc>:r/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid<Enter>ib5806d69-1612-44aa-a30c-9b4312a99b5c_
```

(I denoted final cursor position with underscore `_` character.)

Another example could be:

```
Editing some text and now I want `<Esc>:r!date -R<Enter>i` right in place of the command and continue to type uninterrupted._
```

I hope the issue is clear. I use the `:r[!]...` command many times a day and the extra new line inserted before the content read in the buffer is *extremely annoying* and *disrupting* for you have to move around, delete the extra new line etc. Does some way exist that would be as easy to run as is the `:r[!]...` command and without plugins (just using `*map`ings for example, because I generally use Vi(m) without any extras or tweaks)? All ideas are welcome.

---

Some ideas... Perhaps *normal mode* mapping could be the most useful because then it could be `q`-recorded and replayed at, say, all places where needed in the buffer or (not sure) just run and repeated with `.` normal mode command too. The issue is that I do not generally know how to get prompt for a command from within a mapping. If this was possible then it would be fairly easy to workaround.

Comment: Funny enough, a similar question was asked an hour before this one: [cursor positioning after pasting content in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76470112/cursor-positioning-after-pasting-content-in-vim). I guess one could derive a solution from those answers.

Comment: @Friedrich But that is not similar question at all if I haven't missed something. What I need is to do `:r[!]...` and then `kJ$a` in one shot, I think. For example, if it was possible to set normal mode sequence and hook it somewhere after the `r[!]...` command line mode command run, that would also solve it (but that's not possible, I think).

Comment: See `:h i_ctrl-r` and `:h system()`.

Comment: @romainl Well, this works but it still lacks ergonomics. I can now (in insert mode) do `<Ctrl-R>=system("date -R")<CR>` and it does the job. The ergonomy is quite painful still, for example the `STDERR` is also included which is not good (i.e., if you try to `find /proc -name uuid -exec cat {} +` you have to add `2>/dev/null` redirect because ordinary user does not have rights to access some portions of the `/proc` subsystem). Also, inside the string for the `system()` function you cannot use completion. It's a pity that the `r[ead]` command does not come with an option to supress the newline.

Comment: Does a way to get prompt for *normal mode* mapping exist? I guess there is no such feature. But what about to place a mark, type command normally in the edited text, then call some mapping in normal mode that would execute what's between the mark and cursor position in the buffer and substitute it with the result of the system call. Is this achievable? (This is sort of Plan9 thinking...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help :read` makes it pretty clear that the new text will be inserted on a new line below the current/given one:

> Insert the file [name] (default: current file) below the cursor.

There is *no* way to change that behavior, so you are left with two options:

1. somehow work around the quirks of `:read`,
2. look for an alternative to `:read`.

Here is how a quick and dirty implementation of #1 could look, from insert mode:

```
<CR>                        " split the line at cursor
<Esc>                       " leave insert mode
:-read /path/to/file<CR>    " insert content of file below line above
                            " leaving cursor on first inserted line
-                           " move cursor up
v']+                        " visually select until line below last inserted line
J                           " join
```

That's not a lot of work, but that's a kind of work I don't really like and a kind I wouldn't want to have to do often. Too pedestrian for my taste.

#2 is a good opportunity to dive into vimscript. Here is how it would look, again from insert mode:

```
<C-r>=system('cat /path/to/file')->trim()<CR>
```

where:

- `<C-r><register>` inserts content of `<register>`,
- `=<expression>` puts the result of the evaluation of `<expression>` into register `=`,
- `system('<external command>')` captures the output of `<external command>`,
- `->trim()` removes the EOL, if any.

Which is a *very* different way of interacting with both your text and your editor. Much more high-level and deliberate. I don't know about you but I find the idea of editing (at least some of) my stuff *programmatically* quite appealing.

Of course, you could generalize both solutions and turn them into mappings. Speaking of mappings, here is an insert mode one that does just what you want, prompt and all:

```
inoremap <expr> <key> input('Cmd: ')->system()->trim()
```

See `:help 'shellredir'` if `stderr` is worrying you… or you could simply append  `2>/dev/null` to the output of `input()`.

For manually replacing a visually selected external command with its output, you can do something like this, from visual mode:

```
c<C-r>=getreg('"')->system()->trim()<CR>
```

which is easy to turn into a mapping:

```
xnoremap <key> c<C-r>=getreg('"')->system()->trim()<CR><Esc>
```

Reference:

```
:help :read
:help :range
:help '[
:help J
:help i_ctrl-r
:help registers
:help system()
:help trim()
:help :map-expression
:help input()
:help getreg()
:help v_c
```

Comment: Don't ask if $THING exists. Search for it or make it.